# Does it make sense to include my freelance website in my resume?

Tags: resume, work-experience, freelancing

I have website powered by Wordpress, by using the website I get some small clients. But the company I am working based on .Net technology.

Shall I include Wordpress as my experience and point my URL as project I have done?

Edit: I try to switch another company. So i want to put i am a wordpress developer in my resume.

Comment: You can point out the website. But some companies have strict restrictions on you working for someone else(either a different company or freelance) at the time you are employed with them. I suggest you do some digging around and find out if it would lead to legal issues. (Especially since you have said that you get "small clients" through your website).

Comment: Please update your question: 'include Wordpress as experience' where? - Are you applying for a job elsewhere?

Comment: What makes you think applying for a job as a WordPress developer would be hindered by including your website?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally you should put in your resume those things that emphasize that you are the right person for the job. So it will depend on the job you are applying for.

If you feel your skills as Wordpress developer in any way contribute to the job, mention the website; otherwise, leave it off.